# UISearchController UITableView display on rotate

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, rotation, uisearchcontroller

I have implemented a UISearchController with a UITableView and it's working nice but there're is a problem on rotate.

So if I take the focus on the search bar in portrait mode and then rotate while keeping the focus, here the problem :

**Portrait mode to landscape while focus**

[image]

And I need to Cancel to ge back the search bar display nicely.
Same thing, if I take focus on the search bar in landscape mode and then rotate while keeping the focus, here the problem :

**Landscape mode to portrait while focus**

[image]

You can see the search bar doesn't like to rotate.
**What could possibly be causing this and how to fix it ?**

```
@IBOutlet weak var locationTable: UITableView!

var locationSearchController = UISearchController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.locationTable.delegate = self
    self.locationTable.dataSource = self

    self.locationSearchController = ({

        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
        controller.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controller.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .Minimal
        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        controller.definesPresentationContext = true;
        self.locationTable.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar

        return controller
    })()
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solutiona? I'm stuck just like you were with no luck. All I've done so far is that I debugged the view as deep as I could and I found that when rotating, the whole search bar gets replaced by a UIView for a moment, then gets back to be the search bar again and it leaves behind some kind of artifact in the view hierarchy that extends table view's header so much that we can see this gap above he search bar 1/2

Comment: It seems to me that search bar is trying to leave enough space for `scopeButtons`, but I cannot say for sure because the gap varies in height from time to time which makes understanding the problem even harder. I have tried almost anything with no luck and it seems like a bug and a real bad one. I simply can't use this in my application and I have to think about something else. 2/2

Answer (score 2):

I haven't had *exactly* this problem but for a similar UISearchController-puts-the-table-in-the-wrong-place-in-landscape I found that adding the following to the parent controller fixed it (sorry, Objective-C).

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeAll;
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;
```